# Server error 500 on MAMP after attempted transfer of existing wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I am trying to copy a live wordpress site and make it work locally on MAMP. But when I load up the site I get a 500 error.

What I did.

Downloaded whole site from ftp server and placed in MAMP htdocs directory in a folder.

Exported SQL Database from live site.

Started MAMP and imported sql database.

Added user with privileges for the imported database (with same name and password from live site)

Edited wp-options siteurl and home to http://localhost:8888/

Changed the DB_HOST to localhost in wp-config.php

wouldn't work so installed new a wordpress site in a separate directory in htdocs to see what would happen and that works.

What do I do?

The most recent from log

[Tue Dec 15 16:00:37 2015] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/websites/docs-assets, referer: http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English
[Tue Dec 15 16:26:49 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 15 16:34:01 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 15 16:34:01 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 15 16:34:01 2015] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 6169)
[Tue Dec 15 16:34:01 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 PHP/5.6.10 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.0 configured -- resuming normal operations

most recent SQL log

151215 16:26:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
151215 16:34:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
151215 16:34:01 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
151215 16:34:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151215 16:34:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151215 16:34:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151215 16:34:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151215 16:34:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151215 16:34:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151215 16:34:01 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
151215 16:34:01  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
151215 16:34:02 InnoDB: 5.5.42 started; log sequence number 4458593
151215 16:34:02 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
151215 16:34:02 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.42'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  Source distribution

PHP log when I reload site

[15-Dec-2015 16:47:21 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  require_once(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/websites/cakesandcatering/wp-config.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/websites/cakesandcatering/wp-load.php on line 29
[15-Dec-2015 16:47:21 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/websites/cakesandcatering/wp-config.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/websites/cakesandcatering/wp-load.php on line 29

line 29 on load.php is

```
/** The config file resides in ABSPATH */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' );
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: I have added the log files to the question.